# Are there any tools to convert markdown to Wiki text in other formats

Tags: mediawiki, markdown

The requirement is that I need to paste a long document in markdown format to a mediawiki site, which has no markdown extension installed.
All I can find about markdown, tools or modules/libraries, are in charge of converting markdown to HTML.
My question is: is there a convenient way to do the work from markdown to MediaWiki wikitext?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Try [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/), a universal document converter:

```
$ pandoc --help
pandoc [OPTIONS] [FILES]
Input formats:  docbook, haddock, html, json, latex, markdown, markdown_github,
                markdown_mmd, markdown_phpextra, markdown_strict, mediawiki,
                native, opml, rst, textile
Output formats: asciidoc, beamer, context, docbook, docx, dzslides, epub, epub3,
                fb2, html, html5, json, latex, man, markdown, markdown_github,
                markdown_mmd, markdown_phpextra, markdown_strict, mediawiki,
                native, odt, opendocument, opml, org, pdf*, plain, revealjs,
                rst, rtf, s5, slideous, slidy, texinfo, textile
```

It's available for [virtually every platform](http://pandoc.org/installing.html).

Comment: $ pandoc -r textile input.text -t mediawiki -o output.wiki

Comment: When I used Pandoc to convert from reStructuredText to MediaWiki, I found that it converted footnotes/references to <ref> tags which required a particular MediaWiki plugin I didn't have.  I'm not sure what other assumptions it might make about your MediaWiki install.  It also didn't seem to process explicit links to section titles (e.g. "`Section title`_") properly.

Comment: Pandoc doesn't convert Markdown to  Wikipedia very successfully as doshea notes. A pity there isn't a better, real world suggestion.

Comment: This worked for me: `pandoc input.md -t mediawiki -o output.wiki `

Comment: Had some issues with smart quotes, which is [apparently weird with Markdown](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#typography). When I specified [CommonMark](https://commonmark.org/) as the "from" format, that resolved (though ellipses are still an issue): `pandoc -f commonmark markdownfile.md -t mediawiki -o out.wiki`